# How to calculate the spin of an atom

Tags: atomic-physics, quantum-spin, fermions, bosons, quantum-statistics

If given an atom say ${^{108}_{47}Ag}$, what is the systematic way to determine its spin so that one knows whether it is a boson or a fermion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count up  the total number of protons, neutrons and electrons. If the total  is odd it's a fermion; if even, a boson. No compicated spinology needed.